# How to use Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 API with vb.net service app

Tags: vb.net, google-analytics-api

I have managed to autenticate my self succesfully to google etc. but now I need help how to use Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 or Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data dll to retrive data. for example I need last month vistors. So far I have this:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Threading
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports MailBee
Imports MailBee.ImapMail
Imports MailBee.SmtpMail
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Google.Apis.Analytics.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Util


Public Class gaimport

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Shared Sub Main(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim serviceAccountEmail As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
        Dim userEmail As String = "xxxxx@gmail.com"

        Dim certificate As New X509Certificate2("c:\works\gaimport\gaimport\Analyticsdata-xxxxxxxxxxxx.p12", _
            "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)

        Dim credential As New ServiceAccountCredential( _
            New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) With { _
            .Scopes = New String() {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"} _
        }.FromCertificate(certificate))

        If credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result Then
            Dim xoauthKey As String = OAuth2.GetXOAuthKeyStatic(userEmail, credential.Token.AccessToken)



            Console.WriteLine("test" & xoauthKey)


        End If

    End Sub







End Class
```

Now I need somehing to get analytics part working. how do I use Those dll? Can I reguest feed from google (like i didi with clientId logins)?

Comment: next step try and figure out how to make an AnalyticsService by using your credential.  once you create the service you will be able to make requests against data.ga.get .  Cant help much I only have C# examples.

Comment: That's the problem... Stuck with what to do now. Some wery simple c# example would help too.

Comment: I have a series with C# http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-core-csharp/  my VB is very rusty that is why I haven't done VB tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good traight forfard solution to my case (after getting acces token):

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Dim requesturl = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A" & domainidid(domainrno) & "&start-date=" & viimekuunalkuset & "&end-date=" & viimekuunloppuset & "&metrics=ga%3Ausers%2Cga%3Asessions%2Cga%3Apageviews&access_token=" & credential.Token.AccessToken

Dim resultb As String = webClient.DownloadString(requesturl)
```

Then I just handeled JSON to get what I really wanted to get:

```
Dim myJ = JObject.Parse(resultb)
                Dim totalsForAllResults = Convert.ToInt32(myJ("totalsForAllResults")("ga:sessions"))
                Dim totalsForAllResultsusers = Convert.ToInt32(myJ("totalsForAllResults")("ga:users"))
                Dim totalsForAllResultspgw = Convert.ToInt32(myJ("totalsForAllResults")("ga:pageviews"))
```